# python-MEEP simulation of complex medium

Tags: python, differential-equations, meep, finite-difference, polarization

I am thinking about the following implementation of MEEP:
`P = epsilon_0 E + Q`

where 'Q' is governed by a set of differential equations.
For example:
`d^2Q/dt^2 - w^2 Q = Q1^2`
`d^2Q1/dt^2 -w1^2Q1 = E + QQ1`

I know in simple cases this can be described by Drude-Lorentz model or chi(3). However, is it possible to implement more general differential equations in MEEP, such as the one in above example? or is there any other code that does this?

Thanks a lot!

I could not find any python-MEEP interface that allows me to modify the field values during simulations.